# Laravel 5.3 - Prepend item to paginator data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this paginator instance returned:

```
$products =
{
  "products": 3,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "product_type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "type": "kitchen",
      "product_id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to add an item as the first item to the `data` key like this:

```
$firstItem = {
  "item": "should be first in data",
  "code": 12345
}
```

Final result should look like this:

```
$products =
{
  "products": 3,
  "per_page": 10,
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {                                    <-
      "item": "should be first in data", <-
      "code": 12345                      <-
    },                                   <-
    {
      "id": 4,
      "product_type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": "electronic",
      "product_id": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "type": "kitchen",
      "product_id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried so many ways but none of them get the result.
Any idea how to accomplish the final result?

Comment: Have you tried once you have paginated the data doing `array_unshift($products['data'], $firstItem)`?

Comment: Yup, that gives me `Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\\Pagination\\LengthAwarePaginator has no effect`

Comment: You need to get the data as an array from the `LengthAwarePaginator` instance. Try doing `$products = $products->toArray()` Then do the code I originally posted.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but went with the `prepend` method as it is easier to implement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an instance of Paginated result in `$products` then you may use something like the following to prepend a new item into data, for example:

```
// Get the paginated data
$products = \App\Product::paginate(10);

// Create a new item and populate
$item = new \StdClass;
$item->item = "should be first in data";
$item->code = 12345;

// Insert the new item at top
$products->prepend($item);
```

That's it. The new `StdClass` (Not a an Eloquent Model) item will be prepended at the top.

Comment: `prepend` makes it so much easier. Thank you!